# Xamarin.Forms Android Binding library error

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am currently facing an issue about Xamarin Forms Android Bindings library.
I've put a .jar library inside my bindings project and I realize that the library is not fully loaded.

When I build my bindings project it compiles properly but I still have some warnings in my output.

> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8102: Class Java.Util.LinkedHashMap has unknown base type Java.Util.HashMap.
>
> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8103: Class Com.MyParams has invalid base type java.util.LinkedHashMap.
>
> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8701: Invalid return type com.MyParams in method GetParams in managed type Com.TagOp.
>
> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type com.MyParams in method TagOps in managed type Com.TagOp.
>
> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type com.MyParams in method TagOps in managed type Com.TagOp.
>
> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type com.MyParams in method TagPage in managed type Com.Tag.

In my Android code I can't use the `Com.MyParams` class because it's not loaded.

This problem occurs since the update of Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017.

Do you have any leads to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check your Android project source code, did that project dependency other libraries? If so you need to import other libraries into your binding project.

Comment: My Android project references the Xamarin libraries and my Binding project.  When I see the `obj/` folder of my binding project my `com.MyParams` is not generated. So my guess is that the binding project doesn't generate this class because the warning I've posted on my main post.

Comment: "This problem occurs since the update of Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017.", Do you mean it is good when you didn't update Xamarin? What is the version?

Comment: I've updated Xamarin in May and it won't work any more on VS2017. I'm using Xamarin 4.5.0.486

Comment: I have a general guide you can walk through: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb As many pointed out before, you are most likely missing a dependency library which generates these types.

Answer (score 2):

[HashMap](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.HashMap/) & [LinkedHashMap](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.LinkedHashMap/) are not known ...therefore nothing based upon them can be instanced.

When the data-binding does not know a class, then it either lacks the annotations, it might not extend class `BaseObservable` and/or has wrongful `get` / `set` method names (which need to match the name of the field); there are quite a few conditions to meet, depending if one-way or two-way data-binding is required. Reviewing the generated code often gives a clue what one has to change.

However, directly data-binding the JAR classes does not even appear possible, unless adding the required annotations into them and then building the JAR, in order to have them bind-able. The documentation of the Android [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and Xamarin [Java Bindings Metadata](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/) explains it (replicating the required Java classes from scratch, perfectly bind-able, might be the most fast-forward, if not the only way).

One can only work around it, by substituting the classes to be bound to the GUI - which is possible with rather simple classes, or when using a Java [decompiler](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine/src/org/jetbrains/java/decompiler) (in order to know the fields to use).

Comment: So I need to tell the binding generator to extend the `LinkedHashMap` class with `HashMap` ? I tried `<attr path="/api/package[@name='java.util']/class[@name='LinkedHashMap']" name="extends">java.util.HashMap</attr>` but got the error : `1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8A04: <attr path="/api/package[@name='java.util']/class[@name='LinkedHashMap']"/> matched no nodes.`

Comment: nope; you need the source code of the classes in the JAR or recreate something alike them... one can't just take any class and bind it, because the data-binding expects specific method-names & annotations; eg. `@Bindable` for getters... without these, the methods won't be exposed. while I actually maintain a codebase with lots of bound UI elements, third party libraries, etc... and tried what you try to do already, despite in Java - while there is no way - one can only put effort behind it to recreate the required classes, but bind-able.... or create classes, barely for binding them + the JAR

Comment: ... still find it strange, that not even these common classes are being found; are you sure to have the JDK installed and referenced?

Comment: I was using the JDK from september 2016 and just updated to the latest version and the problem remains the same. I don't have the source code of the library, and it used to work on previous versions of Xamarin. Since the update of may (I think it was may update) the warnings appeared and now I can't compile my Android version anymore because of this missing type.

Comment: @Eastrall there is an open bug on the Xamarin bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58187 ...while it links to this question. attempting a fresh, minimal install could at least sort out a broken IDE (the updater might patch files, not always install them).

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/ here are some VS.NET specific troubleshooting hints... while the absent classes should ordinary be contained within the `rt.jar` (runtime) of the JDK... as one can see here: https://github.com/xamarin/proguard/blob/master/examples/applications.pro ... it says `-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar` (ProGuard is a Java obfuscator)... when explicitly referencing the `rt.jar` and also setting it as `libraryjars` won't change the situation... then I really don't know.

Comment: yes I have opened an issue on their bug tracker about this problem. I tried to update my Java and Android SDK but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what I mean was, to reinstall the whole VS.NET from scratch, hence the update patcher "might have" broken something (the JetBrains updater per default tries to patch, while it installs in case one had edited a file). and when you say, it broke with the update... there might be a relation. downgrading to the last known working version, while skipping this one broken version, might be the other option.